# Hardy's approximation for the cosine

Tags: trigonometry, approximation

I was reading about the Hardy's approximation for the cosine function ([here](https://archive.lib.msu.edu/crcmath/math/math/c/c714.htm) and also in [Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Cosine.html)):

$$\cos \left(\frac{\pi}{2} x\right) \approx 1-\frac{x^{2}}{x+(1-x) \sqrt{\frac{2-x}{3}}}$$
For $0<x<1$

What I would like to know is, how was this approximation derived? What other uses does it have? The links also include a graph showing the error between $\cos(x)$ and the approximation. There isn't much information on the internet about this interesting formula.

Comment: I've read the paper refered in MathWorld, but I found nothing about this cosine approximation in it.

Comment: In the link I added, it's at equation (8), starting at the "A close approximation to cos(pix/2) for x in [0,1] is" line.

Comment: Yes. I know. And there is a referred paper to Hardy 1959 p. 68, but I found nothing there about it.

Comment: The same question has been recently also asked [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Reference_desk/Mathematics#September_26), on *Wikipedia Mathematics Reference Desk*.

Comment: While I agree that the approximation is interesting, there needs to be a specific question suitable for answering in the Math.SE format in order for this to be a good Question.  For example, one might emphasize "how was this approximation derived?" in the context of Hardy's writings.  If the Hardy paper referred to is not apt, that lends to the Reader's confusion.

Comment: I redoubled my efforts to track down the writings of Hardy.  The citations of a kind given by Wolfram/MathWorld, likely copied from other Web pages, lead to a *book* RamanujanL: Twelve Lectures... by Hardy (1940 and republished in 1959, etc.) on subjects inspired by the work of Ramanujan.  The table of contents and searches inside the book by Google Books and Amazon do not reveal a likely page citation. Page 68 in particular is in chapter 5, on A Lattice Point Problem.

Comment: Short of trudging to the library to make a visual inspection, there seems little evidence to follow on this trail.  Of course the pagination of a newer edition might differ from the original (Hardy himself died in 1947), and Amazon seems to offer a 1999 reprint "with additional corrections" (2002) as the displayed edition.

Answer (score 8):

*(Cross posting my answer from the Wikipedia help desk.)*

Here is a way you might reverse engineer the formula, though I have no idea how Hardy derived it.

Let $C(x) = \cos(πx/2)$. We know from the Taylor series that:$$C(x) = 1 - \frac{x^2}{\text{constant}} + \text{other terms}$$

Rewrite this as $C(x) = 1 - \frac{x^2}{K(x)}$ where K is to be determined. We also know $C(1) = 0$ from which $K(1)=1$. Expand $K$ at $x=1$ to get:
$$K(x)=1+(\text{constant})\cdot (x-1)+\text{higher terms}$$

Again, collecting the the constant and higher terms into a single function, write $K(x)=1+(x-1)L(x)$.

At this point you can get a fairly good approximation for $C$ by plugging in a linear approximation for $L$. But we also know $C(1/2)=\sqrt{2}/2$ which would imply (after some computation) $L(1/2) = 1 - \sqrt{1/2}$. So, perhaps a better approximation of $L$ would be: $$L(x)\approx 1 -\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}+m(x-\frac 1 2)}$$ (For some constant m.)

If you plug in $C(2/3)=1/2$ you get $m=-1/3$ which produces the approximation given, but other values of $m$ might work just as well or better. I found $m=-.337$ gives the lowest mean square error on the interval.

Note that there are points in the derivation where different choices could be made, for example you could write $C(x) = 1 - x^2⋅K(x)$ or $K(x)=1+\frac{(x-1)}{L(x)}$. It might be fun to explore these variations to see how they compare with the one given.

Comment: I have edited your post to make use of $\LaTeX$.  Please look it over to ensure that I haven't inadvertently changed the intent of your post.

Comment: @anorton - Looks good, thanks!